# For tuple in list, if 3rd element of tuple is in dicionary, replace the element with the value

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples:

```
my_list = [(a1, b1, c1), ... , (an, bn, cn)]
```

I also have a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {x1: y1, ... , xm: ym}
```

I want to create a function that will search through the 3rd element of each tuple in my_list against my_dict. If the 3rd element of the tuple is in my_dict, replace the element with its value in the dictionary and append this updated tuple to a new list new_list. If the 3rd element of the tuple is not in my_dict, then return the original tuple unchanged to new_list.

So for example if c has value q in the dictionary then I would like to replace c with q:

(a, b, c) ---> (a, b, q)

If c is not in the dictonary the I would like the tuple to remain unchanged:

(a, b, c) ---> (a, b, c)

I have written a for loop but do not understand why it isn't working:

```
def my_func(a,b):
    y = []
    for x in a:
        if b.get(x[2]) == None:
            y.append(x)
        else:
            y.append((x[0], x[1], b.get(x[2])))
    return y
```

So then I aim to evaluate my_func(my_list, my_dict). However, it just returns the original list my_list with no changes. I have tried several other forms such as "if x[2] in my_dict" etc. with no luck.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions!

Edit:

An example of list and dictionary would be:

```
my_list = [ (‘string1_1’, 0.3, ‘string2_1’), (‘string1_2’, 0.5, ‘string2_2’), (‘string1_3’, 0.4, ‘string2_3’), (‘string1_4’, 0.65, ‘string2_4’)]

my_dict = {‘string2_1’:  ‘string2_1_EDIT’,  ‘string2_4’ : ‘string2_4_EDIT’}
```

Comment: Can you give us real examples of `my_list` and `my_dict` for which it does not work?

Comment: Hi Anand! my_list is composed of tuples that are of the form (string, number, string) and the dictionary is String:String e.g. ('BestBuy', 0.3212343, 'AutoZone-3df0a943') is in my_list and corresponding entry in my_dict is {'AutoZone-3df0a943' : CostCo}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simplifiy it down to a list expression:

```
[(x[0], x[1], b.get(x[2], x[2])) for x in a]
```

which should work - can you supply some sample input?

Comment: I like the look of this answer, very pythonic, I think you are missing a ) after the get function though. Unfortunately it doesn't work here, it just returns None

Comment: can you update your question with a sample list and dict with, say, 4-5 entries each that we can use to test the various code snippets.

Comment: okay this definitely works and is very compact. The reason it wasn't working for me before is because the dictionary is in unicode and the list is in standard strings (D'oh!)

Answer (score 1):

It really helps to use more meaningful names for your variables.

The `.get()` method of dicts can take a second argument, which is returned when the key isn't found.

```
my_list = [("a1", "b1", "c1"),  ("an", "bn", "cn")]
my_dict = {"c1": "present"}

def myfunc(lst, dct):
    result = []
    for a, b, c in lst:
        el3 = dct.get(c, c)
        result.append((a, b, el3))
    return result

print myfunc(my_list, my_dict)
```

This prints

```
[('a1', 'b1', 'present'), ('an', 'bn', 'cn')]
```

A more compact version would read

```
def myfunc(lst, dct):
    return [(a, b, dct.get(c, c)) for (a, b, c) in lst]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this certainly looks like it should work. This hasn't in my case though, it just returns each tuple unchanged. This suggest that there must be something wrong with my list and/or dictionary.

Comment: You don't need the brackets around the second (a, b, c) in the list-comprehension version - just to make it even more compact. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following works with your example:

```
my_list = [ ('string1_1', 0.3, 'string2_1'), ('string1_2', 0.5, 'string2_2'), ('string1_3', 0.4, 'string2_3'), ('string1_4', 0.65, 'string2_4')]

my_dict = {'string2_1': 'string2_1_EDIT', 'string2_4' : 'string2_4_EDIT'}

my_list[:] = [(a,b, my_dict.get(c, c)) for a,b,c in my_list]

print my_list
```

Giving the following output:

```
[('string1_1', 0.3, 'string2_1_EDIT'), ('string1_2', 0.5, 'string2_2'), ('string1_3', 0.4, 'string2_3'), ('string1_4', 0.65, 'string2_4_EDIT')]
```